# Python: argument parser - multiple arguments without "--" allowed, not required

Tags: python, argparse

I am struggling to write a simple python script (a pseudo-git), which will allow me to call it from commandline/shell using comand like this:

```
$ python script.py init
```

I found some solutions online, which enabled me to do so, but there is little issue though. I want "add" function to accept other arguments as well (strings in general, which will represent files' names).

I have found a workaround, but it doesn't look nice. Is there a way to refactor the code, so that "add" will accept also other arguments and let me access them later on? Important thing: I don't want them to be added with "--", I'd rather separate them by simply adding space between two arguments.

I found "nargs='+' option in add_argument, but I don't know how to redirect the argument to call a proper function.

Here is my code I wrote so far:

```
import argparse
import sys

def init():
    print("init method call")

def add():
    if(len(sys.argv)>2):
        print("valid add method call")
    else:
        print("invalid call")

def commit():
    print("commit method call") 

def status():
    print("status method call") 

def test():
    print("test method call")   

FUNCTION_MAP = {'init' : init,
                'status' : status,
                'commit': commit}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if(len(sys.argv)>1 and sys.argv[1] == "add"):
        add()
    else:           
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
        parser.add_argument('command', choices=FUNCTION_MAP.keys())
        args = parser.parse_args()
        func = FUNCTION_MAP[args.command]
        func()
```

Comment: You should use: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html

Comment: using the docs linked above you can look at making the `init()`, `add()` and `commit()` as subparsers that way you can have certain flags for each function.

Comment: but will I be able to call them without '-' of '--'? I have already found those docs, but after skimming through them I got different feeling and decided to ask SO community instead.

Edit: what's more I want add to accept more arguments

Comment: [Click](http://click.pocoo.org/6/) could be useful for your case, particularly `@click.argument`

Comment: @Adonis thanks, but I'd rather stay with argparse for this example

Comment: I'm not quite sure where your problem is, whether it's in defining other `positional` arguments, setting up `subparsers`, or using the results after parsing.

Comment: @hpaulj Sorry, I thought I specified my problem quite clear. I can't find a solution to let "add" accept more arguments to be run like:
"python script.py add file1.txt" or "python script.py add all".
I don't want any flags between add and file1.txt

The only way it's working now to have "if" under main

Comment: Either use `subparsers`, or define a second positional with `nargs='?'` or '*'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are 2 options - take an extra positional, and use or ignore the values.  Or use subparsers.

```
import argparse

def add(args):
    print("add:", args)

def status(args):
    values = getattr(args,'values',None)
    if values and len(values)>0:
        # error message and method of your choice
        print('oops - got values', args)
    print("status method call")

FUNCTION_MAP = {'add' : add,
                'status' : status}

if __name__ == '__main__':

        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
        parser.add_argument('command', choices=FUNCTION_MAP.keys())
        parser.add_argument('values', nargs='*')
        args = parser.parse_args()
        func = FUNCTION_MAP[args.command]
        func(args)

        print('\nWIth subparsers')
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
        sp = parser.add_subparsers(dest='command')
        spp = sp.add_parser('add')
        spp.add_argument('values', nargs='*')
        spp = sp.add_parser('status')
        args = parser.parse_args()
        func = FUNCTION_MAP[args.command]
        func(args)
```

Sample runs

```
1906:~/mypy$ python3 stack49691897.py add 1 2 3
add: Namespace(command='add', values=['1', '2', '3'])

WIth subparsers
add: Namespace(command='add', values=['1', '2', '3'])
1907:~/mypy$ python3 stack49691897.py status
status method call

WIth subparsers
status method call
1907:~/mypy$ python3 stack49691897.py status 1 2 3
oops - got values Namespace(command='status', values=['1', '2', '3'])
status method call

WIth subparsers
usage: stack49691897.py [-h] {add,status} ...
stack49691897.py: error: unrecognized arguments: 1 2 3
```

The argparse docs also demonstrates a way of using subparsers and defaults  that effectively implements your `FUNCTION_MAP`.

Comment: Thank you @hpaulj  :) I will look into that!
But is it possible not to specify accepted values for add, but say we can take everything and deal with validating it later in the code?

Comment: Play with `parse_known_args`.